# Multiple selections between characters using lookarounds with regex?

Tags: regex

so I need to match any number of A's and Z's that are between the string AAA and ZZZ.  For example, the string `AAZZAZAAAZAZAZZZAZAZ` would find the match `ZAZA`.

My regex for that is `(?<=[A]{3})[AZ]+(?=[Z]{3})`, which works fine, until I get a string that has 2 or more correct matches in it.  `AZAAA ZZAA ZZZAZAZAAA ZZAAZZAA ZZZAZAZ` (spaces added for clarity), should match both `ZZAA` and `ZZAAZZAA`, but instead it passes right through the middle and returns a single string `ZZAAZZZAZAAAZZAAZZAA`, which is not cool.  How do I get the lookarounds to select multiple strings?

Comment: You have to assign a rule in this case. I.E. the inner group is not allowed to have one of the delimeters (AAA or ZZZ) in it. Because in reality you are doing balanced text. Example:  `AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make the quantifier *lazy*, i.e. make it match as *few characters as possible*. By default, the quantifier is greedy, i.e. it tries to get the longest match.

```
(?<=[A]{3})[AZ]+?(?=[Z]{3})
#               ^
```

For more information: http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html